# How to remove characters inside parenthesis in r

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a data.table with a column that has to be ordered and the month abbreviation is throwing it off. How can I remove just the month abbreviation from within the parenthesis? I've tried a bunch of gsub variations, but haven't been able to achieve the desired results.

This is what the column looks like:

```
K (May 04)
M (Jun 04)
Q (Aug 04)
```

And I would like it to look like:

```
K (04)
M (04)
Q (04)
```

or

```
K04
M04
Q04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- c("K (May 04)", "M (Jun 04)", "Q (Aug 04)")
gsub("\\([A-Z][a-z]{2} ", "(", x)
```

Or for the second option:

```
gsub(" \\([A-Z][a-z]{2} ([0-9]+))", "\\1", x)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!